# Redirect to GSP failing

Tags: redirect, grails, uri

I'm using grails 2.4.5

In my grails-app/views directory I have a simple file called "test.gsp". Its contents are trivial GSP/HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta name="layout" content="main" />
            <title>TEST</title>
            <style>
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <h1>TEST</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

In a controller action, I have the line:

```
redirect(uri:"/test.gsp");
```

But whenever this line is reached, grails sends me off to the 404 handler.

I've tried enabling UrlMapping logging, and it shows:

```
DEBUG mapping.DefaultUrlMappingsHolder  - Matched URI [/test.gsp] with pattern [/(*)/(*)?/(*)?(.(*))?], adding to posibilities
```

I was sure I had this working previously in Grails. What silly thing am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should render a view and not trying to redirect to (probably not mapped) uri.
Try:

```
render(view: "test")
```